# How to avoid remark/warning/error msg from a specific file or library in the makefiles?

Tags: makefile, compiler-errors, gnu-make

I am using external libraries from a manufacturer I am trying to fix all the remarks, but I have found lots of remarks from the libraries of the manufacturer. There is any possibility to skip the messages from the manufacturer libraries?

Comment: Trying to use -isyntax instead of -I, there is an error: C3910W: old syntax, please use '-I'

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).